# can I get php to run in an asp.net page?

Tags: .net, php, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to allow my php pages to run inside a content page of the master page. I'd like to run php somehow inside a master page. Besides frames is there another way? I've read you can use a frame, but would prefer not to.  If I have to go with frames to get it done, should I be using an asp.net frame class of some sort or the raw html type?

Comment: Short of a Web Services type solution, I think you're stuck.

Comment: I'm trying to learn asp.net but I thought it would be nice to use the most popular drop-in blog solution for hosting a coding blog.  Since I imagined finding add-ins for wordpress to do code-coloring and formatting automatically would be easier than finding a .net solution that there's much of a community of support for.

It appears on the last publish my visual studio decided to delete the wordpress directory for no apparent reason and I'm pissed off at VS2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's always [Phalanger](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=Phalanger) for running PHP within the .NET framework, but I recommend against mixing environments like that.

If your PHP pages live on a different server, frame them. If you *must* have them on the same server, Phalanger them.

In both cases, I suggest you take a good, long, hard look at what you're doing and try to find another way.

Comment: the CLR was built to support polyglot programming, so i don't really know that phalanger constitutes mixing environments.

Comment: PHP has a large reliance on a native library that Phalanger must either call directly or emulate. If they call it directly, it's a mixed environment -- the PHP libraries are almost all written in native C. If they emulate them, you're right, it's not a mixed environment. But using PHP with ASP.Net *is* a mixed up way of doing things.

Comment: good point. i looked into this, i checked their info site though (http://php-compiler.net/doku.php?id=core%3aoverview) and they implement the library in managed languages.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is a really bad idea.

Second, if you really want to compound the bad idea, use frames or iframes.  Of course, I hope you don't have Safari clients.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I can think of ONE way.  Do an http request for the php page during execution of your ASPX page.  Filter out everything you don't need and inject the rest.

However, I still stand by my statement about this being a bad idea and believe you are better off throwing the PHP stuff away.  The reason being that the next step in your quest will be to post data back from the php to the .net app; then it really starts going downhill.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Phalanger](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/phalanger-intro.aspx), a php compiler for the CLR

Answer (score 1):

You *could* load the page content from the php sever using ASP.NET...not a good idea, but technically possible.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get php to run within an ASP.NET page.  You can run PHP on an IIS7 install, but it would have to be separate pages, and I don't think that things such as application or session state are transferrable (you would have to store all of that externally, in a DB for example).